# StretchBlt fails when printing

Tags: winapi, printing, gdi

I have a chart (in bitmap format) that I'm trying to render to a printer using `StretchBlt`.  When drawing to the screen, `StretchBlt` works fine.  When drawing to a CutePDF printer, it returns 0, sets the last error to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, and works anyway.  When drawing to a PDF995 printer or a physical HP printer, it returns 0, sets the last error to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, and fails to draw anything.

What would cause `StretchBlt` to fail for certain devices?  I've verified that the source bitmap is a DIB and that the destination supports `StretchBlt` by calling `GetDeviceCaps`.

Here's my code, in case it's relevant:  (It's written in C++Builder, so it uses Delphi's VCL; TCanvas wraps an HDC, and TBitmap wraps an HBITMAP.  VCL provides its own `StretchDraw` function which does not support HALFTONE; I'm getting the same problems with it.)

```
void PrettyStretchDraw(TCanvas *dest, const TRect& rect, TGraphic *source)
{
  if (dynamic_cast<Graphics::TBitmap*>(source) && !source->Transparent) {
    POINT pt;
    GetBrushOrgEx(dest->Handle, &pt);
    SetStretchBltMode(dest->Handle, HALFTONE);
    SetBrushOrgEx(dest->Handle, pt.x, pt.y, NULL);
    StretchBlt(
      dest->Handle,
      rect.Left,
      rect.Top,
      rect.Width(),
      rect.Height(),
      dynamic_cast<Graphics::TBitmap*>(source)->Canvas->Handle,
      0,
      0,
      source->Width,
      source->Height,
      SRCCOPY);
  } else {
    DrawItSomeOtherWay(dest, rect, source);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StretchBlt` is broken on some printer drivers (PDF995 is notable example).

I once encontered this error happening on Windows 2003 Server only (it worked on XP).

Try to reproduce the problem on other OS, and it it does not, consider it OS specific and use `StretchDIBits` instead on this OS.

Comment: StretchDIBits works, and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printingtricksandtips.aspx offers code to create a DIB from a GDI bitmap for passing to StretchDIBits.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoshKelley, could it be that the link shared in your previous comment is dead? Would this link work maybe ? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2474/Printing-tips-and-tricks-from-the-trenches

Comment: @N.Gerontidis, yes, that appears to be the updated link. Thank you.